# Combining a self-extracting zip with batch instructions in a single exe?

Tags: windows, batch-file, winzip

The title is in reference to WinZip's Self-Extracting EXE function and also a program called Batch-to-Exe which converts batch files into an exe file. Would it be possible to combine both things, such that I have a self extracting exe that does certain batch operations before extracting?

Edit: As there are other methods of embedding files in an exe, my question should rather be: What tools are available to embed files in an exe but run batch commands before and after extracting, within the same exe?

*Not asking someone to write code for me, just asking where I can learn to do it myself*

Comment: Yes. This is totally possible.

Comment: Thanks, @MichaelS Can you clarify how?

Comment: Yes, I could. But SO is not a free write-my-code community. You have to show some effort. Show us what you have tried and what exactly is the problem. We won't do your work for you but we are glad to **help** you.

Comment: Type IExpress in Run (Winkey + R) and follow the prompts.

Comment: @MichaelS Toxicity gets you nowhere. Not knowing where to start is precisely the reason I came here.

Comment: @ACatInLove Thanks, I'll look into IExpress!

Comment: @ACatInLove It seems IExpress does not allow inclusion of directories, only files (I may be wrong). Also, I don't believe it it allows for commands before extracting. though it is promising! Anyone know any tools or techniques that may help?

Comment: You said you wanted to put a zip in it.

Comment: @ACatInLove You're not wrong, I wasn't aware of other methods of embedding files in an exe, though that's what I'm interested in. I'll edit the main question.

Comment: To put files into an exe you add it as a resource. However that requires a proper programming language as you have to write the exe file. IExpress is a easy way to do what you want in your language. You use in VB6 `LoadResData` to load a file in an exe into a variable that you can write to file.

Comment: Thank you! That helps a lot and gives me a place to start.

Comment: If using VB6 there is not a way to add many types of resources (though if added by something else it can use them). I use http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/ to add resources to the RES source file that gets compiled into the EXE. API references (that most languages can use incl VB6) are here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff468902(v=vs.85).aspx